react-native-youtube-iframe Play Pause Setting Fullscreen clicks not working
I am using "react-native-youtube-iframe" library to play YouTube videos.
The video starts playing but pause, setting, and full-screen buttons are not working on Android but working fine for iOS. I have build app on react-native 0.72.3.
Earlier with React Native 0.66.5, all touch events were working fine for both platforms.

I had similar problem.
In my case, it was due to FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat.
My react-native-youtube-iframe playwer is inside chat bubble which cause this problem, so i just work around the bubble by if statement.
like this.
<AnimatedBubbleView user={currentMessage.user}>
    {props.currentMessage.video ? (
      <YoutubePlayer
       ...
      />
    ) : (
      <Bubble           
        {...props}
        ...
        // renderMessageVideo={renderVideo}
      />
    )}
  </AnimatedBubbleView>

you might need to check the parent component.
